# facebook fql - get friends of friends list

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graph API - get the Friends of my friend](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3423671/graph-api-get-the-friends-of-my-friend)

assuming my facebook app has permission to access user' friends details,
what is the **fql** query to get list of **user' friends of friends?**

if not fql, is there any way to get it with *graph api*?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to get friends of friends. Your access token only allows you access your friends data, not your friends friends date which includes who they are friends with.

Comment: are you sure? sounds odd. what about other premissions?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. If you do not believe me, feel free to take a look through the documentation for yourself and you will find the same answer.